# Should I set a fixed height or use padding to set the height of a text background?

Tags: html, css

I know this is probably a stupid question. But say I have a navigation menu, would it be more practical to set a fixed height..

```
 nav {
 background: red;
 Width: 80%;
 height: 60px;
 }

 nav ul li {
 Line-height: 60px;
 }
```

Or to use padding to define the height?

```
 nav {
 background: red;
 Width: 80%;
 Padding: 30px 0;
 }
```

I usually go with the first choice. But I'm worried that the font size might change in different computers/browsers and therefore becomes unproportional with the container. Could this actually happen?

Comment: Maybe you can use `min-height` instead of `height`. This way, if your text goes bigger, your menu will resize.

Comment: can u share a fiddle file?

Answer (score 0):

Your vertical padding should probably go on the

```
nav ul li a
```

That way, if the anchor text scales up, so does your header and everything doesn't break out, and you have a larger clickable area. Also, don't leave the anchor display inline.